# Sourcetree not displaying any repository files

Tags: git, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

I have a local git repository. And i have added it to the sourcetree. But sourcetree is displaying it just as a bookmarked repo. No files nothing else is showing. Even after adding some files,committing,pushing. Nothing happening. What should i do. In options menu under Git tab there is "use embedded" /"use system" Git option is available i also tried them. But nothing seems to be working. From cmd everything is working fine.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any uncommitted files, this screen is correct. If you want to see all files, click on the dropdown which currently says "Pending files, sorted by checked / unchecked" and choose "All files".

Comment: Ok, but what do you expect to see? A view like the Windows Explorer with a tree view of all files or something else?